# How to uniquely identify xpath for multiple tags and multiple values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have following html:

```
<div class=‘content active’>
    <div>
        <div class=‘var’>
            <div class=‘field var-field’>
                <label>Interface Name</label>
                <div class=‘ui input’>
                    <input type=‘input’ placeholder=‘.*’ value> ==$0
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class=‘var’>
            <div class=‘field var-field’>
                <label>Neighbor Id</label>
                <div class=‘ui input’>
                    <input type=‘input’ placeholder=‘.*’ value> ==$0
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to send text to the text box with label: Interface Name.
Is there a way to uniquely write the xpath to send the text to the **textbox**. 
Note that the only way to identify uniquely is wrt the label. The other fields in the  tag is same for both. 
I tried using AND operator. No luck. 
Please help me out here.

Comment: What do you mean by `input type=‘input’`? And please show us the XPath you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: @Lutz Horn. Even I felt it very weird. I have not developed this website. This is somehow working. For now, i'm just right clicking the element, then copy xpath and giving * for the maximum possible hierarchy covering. 
i.e., xpath: //*/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/input
This obviously works, but I know this is very bad solution. Hence asked for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
//label[text()='Interface Name']/following-sibling::div/child::input
```

Comment: Works Like a charm !! Thanks Alot !!

Answer (score 0):

To send text to the `<input>` element with respect to the `<label>` tag you can create a function as follows :

```
def test_me(myText):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='" + myText + "']//following::div[1]/input").send_keys("hello")
```

Now, you can call this function from anywhere within your script as follows :

```
test_me("Interface Name")
# or
test_me("Neighbor Id")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this XPATH :- `//*[text()='Interface Name']/following-sibling::div/input"`